# How do I change the featured video on my YouTube channel?

Tags: youtube

How to set the default video for my YouTube channel?

I've uploaded a few videos on YouTube but I can't find anywhere an option to set the default video for my channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To edit your channel trailer,

1. go to your channel
2. click "customize channel"
3. go to the "for new visitors" tab
4. click the pencil in the top-right corner of the card